# How to get angularFire return value and pass to another angularFire?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Let say I get a list of data in controller with below

```
angularFire(url, $scope, 'data');
```

Then there is a `$scope.data.id`. And I how can I use this `id` in another angularFire

```
angularFire(url_with_above_$scope.data.id, $scope, 'anotherData');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of AngularFire only takes references, not URLs. You can just append the ID to the original reference to create your second binding:

```js
var ref = new Firebase(url);
angularFire(ref, $scope, 'data').then(function() {
  angularFire(ref.child($scope.data.id), $scope, 'anotherData');
});
```